# Xamarin forms iOS app crash log showing crashes, how to figure it out?

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

we have a complex app

Here is crash logs, Crash is randomly so how can we figure it out

This is crash logs from app store, they are showing only very abstract information.

```html
Incident Identifier: C72819C8-A626-43C8-A8CD-6DAC8CF739AD
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             TestDemoApp.iOS [7393]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6C33DC22-A558-4A99-86E8-23681121D29A/TestDemoApp.iOS.app/TestDemoApp.iOS
Identifier:          com.drmaxmuscle.max
Version:             2.6.2036 (2.6.2036)
AppStoreTools:       13F15
AppVariant:          1:iPhone8,1:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Background
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.drmaxmuscle.max [784]

Date/Time:           2022-06-17 16:48:39.6691 -0500
Launch Time:         2022-06-17 06:13:32.4029 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.5 (19F77)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    9.61.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGKILL)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4297441280
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   10025c000-10040c000 [ 1728K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  .../TestDemoApp.iOS
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<com.drmaxmuscle.max>:7393 exhausted CPU time allowance of 4.98 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Background
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-create
WatchdogVisibility: Foreground
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.590 (user 13.590, system 0.000), 100% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.602, 41% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - Fault hit memory shortage
VM - Fault hit memory shortage
VM - Fault hit memory shortage

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e3f754 0x10025c000 + 46020436
1   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e1d58c 0x10025c000 + 45880716
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e1d464 0x10025c000 + 45880420
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e3f98c 0x10025c000 + 46021004
4   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102dd79c0 0x10025c000 + 45595072
5   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102de5f68 0x10025c000 + 45653864
6   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001005f2050 0x10025c000 + 3760208
7   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001005f1f68 0x10025c000 + 3759976
8   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001005f5230 0x10025c000 + 3772976
9   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001005f5190 0x10025c000 + 3772816
10  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001005e1970 0x10025c000 + 3692912
11  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013fa580 0x10025c000 + 18474368
12  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013fa4e8 0x10025c000 + 18474216
13  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013fa354 0x10025c000 + 18473812
14  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013f28c8 0x10025c000 + 18442440
15  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013ee988 0x10025c000 + 18426248
16  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000101463afc 0x10025c000 + 18905852
17  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102effbb0 0x10025c000 + 46807984
18  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001003cf3b4 0x10025c000 + 1520564
19  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001003d18fc 0x10025c000 + 1530108
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d16778 -[UIViewController _effectiveHomeIndicatorAutoHiddenViewController] + 100 (UIViewController.m:11826)
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d1678c -[UIViewController _effectiveHomeIndicatorAutoHiddenViewController] + 120 (UIViewController.m:11826)
22  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182da61e8 -[_UISystemAppearanceManager updateHomeIndicatorAutoHidden] + 96 (_UISystemAppearanceManager.m:58)
23  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a588d4 __59-[UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden]_block_invoke_2 + 120 (UIViewController.m:11840)
24  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c2b8e4 -[UIViewController _updateSystemAppearanceWithRecursionBlock:action:] + 324 (UIViewController.m:3557)
25  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c2b830 -[UIViewController _updateSystemAppearanceWithRecursionBlock:action:] + 144 (UIViewController.m:3553)
26  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182e85f74 -[UINavigationController _navigationBarDidChangeStyle:] + 144 (UINavigationController.m:3945)
27  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c6c5e4 -[UINavigationBar _sendNavigationBarDidChangeStyle] + 84 (UINavigationBar.m:984)
28  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182de3e0c -[UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:] + 460 (UINavigationBar.m:1005)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180565dc0 __invoking___ + 144
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180619b34 -[NSInvocation invokeUsingIMP:] + 240 (NSForwarding.m:3414)
31  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c1f3fc __workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget_block_invoke + 80 (UIAppearance.m:1104)
32  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182acd904 +[UIView _performSystemAppearanceModifications:] + 68 (UIView.m:3811)
33  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a710dc applyInvocationsToTarget + 1172 (UIAppearance.m:1100)
34  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d3ede0 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:onlySystemInvocations:] + 1388 (UIAppearance.m:1383)
35  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a8a76c __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 76 (UIView.m:16229)
36  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182df683c -[UIView _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 204 (UIView.m:16238)
37  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182e9d694 -[UINavigationBar _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 56 (UINavigationBar.m:3513)
38  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182ab8fec -[UIView _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 184 (UIView.m:16212)
39  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b1cc98 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1596 (UIView.m:16022)
40  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182acbadc -[UINavigationBar _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 64 (UINavigationBar.m:2700)
41  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b1c9fc -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 928 (UIView.m:15956)
42  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a49684 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 136 (UIView.m:12349)
43  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182ad5294 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 752 (UIView.m:476)
44  UIKitCore                       0x00000001829f7990 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2148 (UIView.m:16778)
45  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b3d588 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 2928 (UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator.m:126)
46  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d0793c ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 72 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:0)
47  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b460a8 +[UIKeyboardSceneDelegate _pinInputViewsForKeyboardSceneDelegate:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 104 (UIKeyboardSceneDelegate.m:2023)
48  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182bb8b14 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.641 + 176 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:1258)
49  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c3f510 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 172 (UIView.m:14564)
50  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182ae2e50 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 572 (UIViewControllerTransitioning.m:1249)
51  UIKitCore                       0x000000018310d874 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.401 + 2152 (UIPresentationController.m:1238)
52  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182bda4f0 +[UIPresentationController _scheduleTransition:] + 96 (UIPresentationController.m:2469)
53  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182eca4a0 -[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState] + 1720 (UIPresentationController.m:1115)
54  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c2c960 -[UIPresentationController _presentWithAnimationController:inWindow:interactionController:target:didEndSelector:] + 928 (UIPresentationController.m:645)
55  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b29078 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 440 (UIWindow.m:2134)
56  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b358a0 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 596 (UIWindow.m:2404)
57  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001014536d8 0x10025c000 + 18839256
58  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013d0e58 0x10025c000 + 18304600
59  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001015bb260 0x10025c000 + 20312672
60  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001015bae20 0x10025c000 + 20311584
61  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001008887b8 0x10025c000 + 6473656
62  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001008db330 0x10025c000 + 6812464
63  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010087f2cc 0x10025c000 + 6435532
64  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000101777c78 0x10025c000 + 22133880
65  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001007dd760 0x10025c000 + 5773152
66  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102d6fcc0 0x10025c000 + 45169856
67  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e29894 0x10025c000 + 45930644
68  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102d54a94 0x10025c000 + 45058708
69  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001007e28f0 0x10025c000 + 5794032
70  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001007229f4 0x10025c000 + 5007860
71  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000101774ec4 0x10025c000 + 22122180
72  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001008813b0 0x10025c000 + 6443952
73  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001015ba738 0x10025c000 + 20309816
74  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010041a948 0x10025c000 + 1829192
75  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001007dd760 0x10025c000 + 5773152
76  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102d6fcc0 0x10025c000 + 45169856
77  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e29894 0x10025c000 + 45930644
78  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e2d0d4 0x10025c000 + 45945044
79  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001003cac1c 0x10025c000 + 1502236
80  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001003cfb78 0x10025c000 + 1522552
81  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b8716c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 336 (UIApplication.m:2334)
82  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d5b740 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3508 (UIApplication.m:2754)
83  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d44e28 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1176 (UIApplication.m:4491)
84  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182bb2d24 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 148 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:450)
85  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a19cf0 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96 (_UISceneLifecycleState.m:109)
86  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b3c5ec __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 188 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:563)
87  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182c51994 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 240 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:512)
88  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182e79dd0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 744 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:562)
89  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182e09b38 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 336 (_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer.m:468)
90  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a1aa3c __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block... + 188 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:73)
91  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182ad650c +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 812 (BSAnimationSettings+UIKit.m:50)
92  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a1c7cc _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 248 (_UISceneSettingsDiffAction.m:23)
93  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182b00d44 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 356 (_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:58)
94  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182f569c0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.578 + 772 (UIScene.m:1825)
95  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a4a474 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248 (UIScene.m:1526)
96  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182a8c0f4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 264 (UIScene.m:1792)
97  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182bb778c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 560 (UIApplication.m:3955)
98  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182aff160 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:45)
99  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000191737c50 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 412 (FBSScene.m:439)
100 FrontBoardServices              0x0000000191759f98 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.180 + 100 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:384)
101 FrontBoardServices              0x000000019171abdc -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232 (FBSWorkspace.m:352)
102 FrontBoardServices              0x000000019171bfd4 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 312 (FBSWorkspaceScenesClient.m:383)
103 libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180298094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
104 libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023b150 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 220 (queue.c:501)
105 FrontBoardServices              0x000000019171c2ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
106 FrontBoardServices              0x000000019171b7c0 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 176 (FBSSerialQueue.m:181)
107 FrontBoardServices              0x000000019171f960 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24 (FBSSerialQueue.m:194)
108 CoreFoundation                  0x00000001805f84ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)
109 CoreFoundation                  0x000000018060861c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)

112 CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180563240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
113 GraphicsServices                0x00000001a1033988 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
114 UIKitCore                       0x0000000182d6341c -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3511)
115 UIKitCore                       0x0000000182afcb88 UIApplicationMain + 336 (UIApplication.m:5064)
116 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000101450568 0x10025c000 + 18826600
117 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001013a6880 0x10025c000 + 18131072
118 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000100419fb4 0x10025c000 + 1826740
119 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001007dd760 0x10025c000 + 5773152
120 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102d6fcc0 0x10025c000 + 45169856
121 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e29894 0x10025c000 + 45930644
122 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e2fb48 0x10025c000 + 45955912
123 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102d4e0ac 0x10025c000 + 45031596
124 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102f0a6fc 0x10025c000 + 46851836
125 TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010040f6fc 0x10025c000 + 1783548
126 dyld                            0x00000001035983d0 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae19484 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db957bd4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102ecca68 0x10025c000 + 46598760
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db951348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f948 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae19688 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180238d60 _dlock_wait + 52 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180238b4c _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp + 52 (lock.c:366)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180245bfc __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 320 (lock.h:330)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180245820 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 136 (queue.c:1774)
5   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182bcd510 __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 112 (_UIRemoteKeyboards.m:1094)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180565dc0 __invoking___ + 144
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180581e98 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300 (NSForwarding.m:3378)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c8c528 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 20 (NSXPCConnection.m:170)
9   Foundation                      0x0000000181cac368 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 568 (NSXPCConnection.m:316)
10  Foundation                      0x0000000181c88328 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 208 (NSXPCConnection.m:1630)
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001db986354 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 60 (serializer.c:119)
12  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001db97a6bc _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 76 (connection.c:833)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018029810c _dispatch_client_callout3 + 16 (object.m:586)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180251840 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 344 (mach.c:2418)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023e610 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 344 (inline_internal.h:0)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023f224 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 456 (queue.c:3944)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180248ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94fe10 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f93c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae19484 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db957bd4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   Foundation                      0x0000000181df9a9c -[_NSThreadPerformInfo wait] + 64 (NSThread.m:261)
3   Foundation                      0x0000000181cfa530 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 744 (NSThread.m:1266)
4   Foundation                      0x0000000181c9a238 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 132 (NSThread.m:1284)
5   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010145daf8 0x10025c000 + 18881272
6   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010137fe78 0x10025c000 + 17972856
7   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010256dc5c 0x10025c000 + 36772956
8   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000101404850 0x10025c000 + 18516048
9   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x00000001014656b8 0x10025c000 + 18912952
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180297094 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1517)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180298094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023e73c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023f224 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 456 (queue.c:3944)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180248ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94fe10 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f93c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001805586c0 _CFRelease + 68 (CFRuntime.c:2080)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180586a68 __CFBasicHashDrain + 308 (CFBasicHash.c:457)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180558788 _CFRelease + 268 (CFRuntime.c:2134)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018055711c __CFBinaryPlistWriteOrPresize + 244 (CFBinaryPList.c:576)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180555830 CFPropertyListWrite + 200 (CFPropertyList.c:3005)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180584934 CFPropertyListCreateData + 140 (CFPropertyList.c:2929)
6   CFNetwork                       0x0000000180df1304 ___ZN12__CFURLCache23CreateAndStoreCacheNodeEP16__CFURLCacheNodePK20_CFCachedURLResponsePK10__CFStringPK13_CFURLRequestPKvbRb_block_invoke + 1528 (NSURLStorageURLCacheDB.mm:979)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180245544 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104 (queue.c:560)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180298094 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:560)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023e73c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 644 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018023f224 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 456 (queue.c:3944)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180248ec8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 632 (queue.c:6732)

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae18b00 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e6bdfc 0x10025c000 + 46202364
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e77398 0x10025c000 + 46248856
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e7721c 0x10025c000 + 46248476
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db951348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f948 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae19484 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db957bd4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1240 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102edc00c 0x10025c000 + 46661644
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e82ac0 0x10025c000 + 46295744
4   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e82998 0x10025c000 + 46295448
5   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e82bbc 0x10025c000 + 46295996
6   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e718c4 0x10025c000 + 46225604
7   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102ded8b8 0x10025c000 + 45684920
8   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055ff88 0x10025c000 + 3161992
9   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055faf4 0x10025c000 + 3160820
10  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055f5fc 0x10025c000 + 3159548
11  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055f5ac 0x10025c000 + 3159468
12  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055f4ac 0x10025c000 + 3159212
13  TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x000000010055f558 0x10025c000 + 3159384

19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94fe10 _pthread_wqthread + 284 (pthread.c:2599)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f93c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f934 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18 name:
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f934 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19 name:
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001917c033c nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$mp + 312 (nanov2_malloc.c:2744)
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001917c0320 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$mp + 284 (locking.h:61)
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001917c01b4 nanov2_malloc$VARIANT$mp + 60 (nanov2_malloc.c:1053)
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001917b6efc _malloc_zone_malloc + 148 (malloc.c:1608)
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39a54f8 sqlite3MemMalloc + 44 (sqlite3.c:25449)
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a3a55920 dbMallocRawFinish + 24 (sqlite3.c:29741)
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39e4d94 sqlite3VdbeMemGrow + 520 (sqlite3.c:29772)
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39a63b4 sqlite3VdbeMemSetStr + 464 (sqlite3.c:84364)
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a3a84dac sqlite3GenerateColumnNames + 1408 (sqlite3.c:88674)
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39ce030 sqlite3Select + 1036 (sqlite3.c:147263)
10  libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39ae3d8 yy_reduce + 1640 (sqlite3.c:170967)
11  libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39acda4 sqlite3RunParser + 1012 (sqlite3.c:172358)
12  libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a39ac360 sqlite3Prepare + 428 (sqlite3.c:140551)

Thread 22 name:
Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae18b00 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e6bdfc 0x10025c000 + 46202364
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e77398 0x10025c000 + 46248856
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e7721c 0x10025c000 + 46248476
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db951348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f948 thread_start + 8

Thread 23 name:
Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae18b00 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e6bdfc 0x10025c000 + 46202364
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e77398 0x10025c000 + 46248856
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e7721c 0x10025c000 + 46248476
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db951348 _pthread_start + 116 (pthread.c:891)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001db94f948 thread_start + 8

Thread 24 name:
Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001bae18b00 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e6bdfc 0x10025c000 + 46202364
2   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e77398 0x10025c000 + 46248856
3   TestDemoApp.iOS                     0x0000000102e7721c 0x10025c000 + 46248476
```

<5190be2141d433619249bfdc03b71e36> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1db96d000 - 0x1db9a5fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <6fd5eb471e0231da85c195502a55c75f> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

Comment: Are you using any crash reporting tools like appcenter.ms?

Answer (score 2):

These crash logs are of very little use if not fully symbolicated.

I would suggest following [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report) to symbolicate the crash report in order to figure out what is happening.